# Convert CSV to YAML, with Unicode?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, unicode, yaml

I'm trying to convert a CSV file, containing Unicode strings, to a YAML file using Python 3.4.

Currently, the YAML parser escapes my Unicode text into an ASCII string.  I want the YAML parser to export the Unicode string *as* a Unicode string, without the escape characters.  I'm misunderstanding something here, of course, and I'd appreciate any assistance.

*Bonus points*: how might this be done with Python 2.7?

**CSV input**

```
id, title_english, title_russian
1, A Title in English, Название на русском
2, Another Title, Другой Название
```

**current YAML output**

```
- id: 1
  title_english: A Title in English
  title_russian: "\u041D\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043D\u0438\u0435 \u043D\u0430\
    \ \u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043A\u043E\u043C"
- id: 2
  title_english: Another Title
  title_russian: "\u0414\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043E\u0439 \u041D\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\
      \u043D\u0438\u0435"
```

**desired YAML output**

```
- id: 1
  title_english: A Title in English
  title_russian: Название на русском
- id: 2
  title_english: Another Title
  title_russian: Другой Название
```

**Python conversion code**

```
import csv
import yaml
in_file  = open('csv_file.csv', "r")
out_file = open('yaml_file.yaml', "w")
items = []

def convert_to_yaml(line, counter):
    item = {
        'id': counter,
        'title_english': line[0],
        'title_russian': line[1]
    }
    items.append(item)

try:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    next(reader) # skip headers
    for counter, line in enumerate(reader):
        convert_to_yaml(line, counter)
    out_file.write( yaml.dump(items, default_flow_style=False) )

finally:
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: YAML is expected to work like this.

Comment: @Javier, can you elaborate? Isn't YAML supposed to be human-readable?

Comment: yep, you are right. I guess it's for interoperability, don't know. See: http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2488852

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and this was how I was able to resolve it based on your example above

```
out_file.write(yaml.dump(items, default_flow_style=False,allow_unicode=True) )
```

including `allow_unicode=True` fixes the issue.

also specifically for python2 make use of `safe_dump` instead of `dump` to prevent the `!!python/unicode` displaying along with the unicode text.

```
out_file.write(yaml.safe_dump(items, default_row_style=False,allow_unicode=True)
```

Comment: @gbozee have you or anyone else been needing to run this code several times in order for the entire .csv file to be converted into a .yaml file?

Comment: The OP implementation was still used just the line `out_file.write( yaml.dump(items, default_flow_style=False) )` which was changed to my answer.
It just needs to be run once per csv file since the for loop goes through each row in the csv file

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, you should use a Unicode CSV reader as Python's CSV reader doesn't support that. You can use [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.4) for this purpose.

In your current Python 3.x code you should explicitly pass the file encoding when opening it:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

It may be that your system is already doing the right thing but you're relying on defaults in that case.

Lastly, you need to make sure the YAML file is opened with the correct encoding: `open("yaml_file.yaml", "w", encoding="utf-8")`. And this encoding should be used later when reading the YAML file.

I'm not sure what the `yaml` library does when given Python objects but you also need to check that `line[0]` and `line[1]` are Unicode strings when you're setting them inside `convert_to_yaml`.

Comment: Thanks very much.  You've helped me to isolate the problem, via your last point: the yaml library seems to escape unicode characters by default.