# Why must I run this code a few times before my entire .csv file is converted into a .yaml file?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, yaml

I am trying to build a tool that can convert .csv files into .yaml files for further use. I found a handy bit of code that does the job nicely from the link below:

[Convert CSV to YAML, with Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888612/convert-csv-to-yaml-with-unicode)

which states that the line will take the dict created by opening a .csv file and dump it to a .yaml file:

```
out_file.write(ry.safe_dump(dict_example,allow_unicode=True))
```

However, one small kink I have noticed is that when it is run once, the generated .yaml file is typically incomplete by a line or two. In order to have the .csv file exhaustively read through to create a complete .yaml file, the code must be run two or even three times. Does anybody know why this could be?

**UPDATE**

Per request, here is the code I use to parse my .csv file, which is two columns long (with a string in the first column and a list of two strings in the second column), and will typically be 50 rows long (or maybe more). Also note that it designed to remove any `'\n'` or spaces that could potentially cause problems later on in the code.

```
csv_contents={}
with open("example1.csv", "rU") as csvfile:
    green= csv.reader(csvfile, dialect= 'excel')
    for line in green:
        candidate_number= line[0]
        first_sequence= line[1].replace(' ','').replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
        second_sequence= line[2].replace(' ','').replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
        csv_contents[candidate_number]= [first_sequence, second_sequence]
        csv_contents.pop('Header name', None)
```

Ultimately, it is not that important that I maintain the order of the rows from the original dict, just that all the information within the rows is properly structured.

Comment: How many rows has your csv file?

Comment: @Hackerman most of the .csv files I am dealing with have 50 rows, but I might need to work with .csv files with more or less rows in the future.

Comment: Can you post your python code and also your csv file inside a repo on github in order to take a look at it?

Comment: @Hackerman I'm sorry, I'm not really sure how to use GitHub, and for a variety of reasons, I cannot post the csv file itself. Can I just post my Python code above?

Comment: Yes, no problem...another question, can you also post the number of columns of your csv and the datatype for each one of the columns?..that way I can build my own csv file for testing the code.

Comment: You should be doing `ry.safe_dump(dict_example, out_file, allow_unicode=True)), instead of the inefficient generation of an in-memory string representation of your file first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what would cause could be but you might be running out of memory as you create the YAML document in memory first and then write it out. It is much better to directly stream it out.

You should also note that the code in the question you link to, doesn't preserve the order of the original columns, something easily circumvented by using `round_trip_dump` instead of `safe_dump`.

You probably want to make a top-level sequence (list) as in the desired output of the linked question, with each element being a mapping (dict).

The following parses the CSV, taking the first line as keys for mappings created for each following line:

```
import sys
import csv
import ruamel.yaml as ry
import dateutil.parser   # pip install python-dateutil


def process_line(line):
    """convert lines, trying, int, float, date"""
    ret_val = []
    for elem in line:
        try:
            res = int(elem)
            ret_val.append(res)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            res = float(elem)
            ret_val.append(res)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            res = dateutil.parser.parse(elem)
            ret_val.append(res)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        ret_val.append(elem.strip())
    return ret_val

csv_file_name = 'xyz.csv'

data = []
header = None
with open(csv_file_name) as inf:
    for line in csv.reader(inf):
        d = process_line(line)
        if header is None:
            header = d
            continue
        data.append(ry.comments.CommentedMap(zip(header, d)))

ry.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout, allow_unicode=True)
```

with input `xyz.csv`:

```
id, title_english, title_russian
1, A Title in English, Название на русском
2, Another Title, Другой Название
```

this generates:

```
- id: 1
  title_english: A Title in English
  title_russian: Название на русском
- id: 2
  title_english: Another Title
  title_russian: Другой Название
```

The `process_line` is just some sugar that tries to convert strings in the CSV file to more useful types and strings without leading spaces (resulting in far less quotes in your output YAML file).

I have tested the above on files with 1000 rows, without any problems (I won't post the output though).

The above was done using Python 3 as well as Python 2.7, starting with a UTF-8 encoded file `xyz.csv`. If you are using Python 2, you can try [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.4) if you need to handle Unicode input and things don't work out as well as they did for me.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth response! At the same time, I should note that I prefer to have a different format in the output .yaml file for structural reasons, so I made some changes to the for-loop that parsed my .csv file. Also, I must ask, could you tell me what `res = dateutil.parser.parse(elem)` does?

Comment: As for the format, I did only have the linked question to go on, the variable name `dict_example` only hinted at the toplevel not being a list/sequence. `dateutil.parser.parse(elem)` tries to make a date(time) out of an element (it uses the package [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)). I do that since `int`/`float`/`datetime` is better handled as native type when dumping YAML (i.e. no additional quotes necessary to "preserve" it as string).